# Setting UINavigationController, old code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have been looking back at some old code from when I first started learning Objective-c and I have a quick question:

```
// THIS IS MY OLD CODE
@implementation syntax_UINavAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UITableViewController *rootController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    [window addSubview:[[self navController] view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

my current understanding is that in the above code there are two issues, firstly I am acessing the property navController directly (I should be using the setter) and secondly do I have a memory leak with `[UINavigationController alloc]`? My gut feeling is that its not a leak as it will get released when I call `[navController release];` in dealloc, BUT that its just messey and a bad way to do things. Here is my (now I know a little more) rework of the same code.

```
// NEW CODE
@implementation syntax_UINavAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UITableViewController *rootController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *tempController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
    [self setNavController:tempController];
    [rootController release];
    [tempController release];

    [window addSubview:[[self navController] view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

just curious ...

Gary

Comment: I would say that you understood right and your gut is probably right most of the time. I would usually pass [tempController view] to the addSubview method just to spare calling the getter and do all of the release of the local variables on a "big" cleanup block just before return but it is really the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, your second code is definitely better than the first. However, I would change a few things. Skip the tempcontroller, instead assign it directly to navController using dot notation. Make sure you call `[navController release]` in `dealloc` though.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UITableViewController *rootController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navController =  [[[UINavigationController alloc]
                              initWithRootViewController:rootController] autorelease];
    [rootController release];

    [window addSubview:self.navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, personally I prefer to release the alloc myself and then let the dealloc release the retain in the property (but thats just my preference) thank you for taking the time to post, much appreciated.